# How to insert code html to textarea using javascript

Tags: javascript

Tell me How To do? 
Here My Script

```
$('code').on('click', function(){
            var cursorPos = $('#spot-template-code').prop('selectionStart');
            var v = $('#spot-template-code').val();
            var textBefore = v.substring(0,  cursorPos );
            var textAfter  = v.substring( cursorPos, v.length );
            $('#spot-template-code').val( textBefore+ $(this).xml() +textAfter );
        });
```

Please How i'd must change? 
after click on the function, nothing happend on my textarea

```
<trans data-id='AFTER'>AFTER</trans>
```

I'd want to insert this code to my textarea ?

Comment: It's really not clear what you're asking or what the problem is with your current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ok, you can do this by enter your code in to any tag and just access html of the control

```js
$('[data-id="AFTER"]').click(function(){
  $('#txtCode').val($('#copy').html()) 
});
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script id="copy">
$('code').on('click', function(){
            var cursorPos = $('#spot-template-code').prop('selectionStart');
            var v = $('#spot-template-code').val();
            var textBefore = v.substring(0,  cursorPos );
            var textAfter  = v.substring( cursorPos, v.length );
            $('#spot-template-code').val( textBefore+ $(this).xml() +textAfter );
        });
        </script>
        <trans data-id='AFTER'>AFTER</trans>
        <textarea id="txtCode"></textarea>
```

Comment: Have you tried your code? It does not seem to do what the OP wants, though that's not 100% clear.

Comment: i am given the example of copy your html into text by click on after

Comment: have it ... and it work 100% . thanks ,,, sorry i've been busy to controlled the script .. thanks by the way master